# Perl: how to test if every element in an array is greater than a value?

Tags: arrays, perl

I need to test a file with each line having the same number of columns and each entry is some value and I want to only select those lines with every values greater than, say 0.5.

I know I can loop through the array in each line by doing something like this:

```
open (IN, shift @ARGV);
while (<IN>){
chomp;
my $count = 0;
my @array = split/\t/;

foreach (@array){
    if ($_ > 0.5) {
       $count ++;
    }
}

if ($count == scalar @array){
   print $_,"\n";
}
}
close IN;
```

This is kinda long and I'm wondering if there is a better way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Apart from using `List::Util`, there's no need to maintain a count (just a condition), nor do you need to keep scanning once you see a value that's <= 0.5. And you should be using the 3-argument version of `open`: `open(my $IN, '<', shift @ARGV)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `all` from [`List::Util`](http://p3rl.org/List%3a%3aUtil) - it checks if passed code block (often with condition) returns true for all elements of list.

```
use List::Util qw(all);

if (all { $_ > 0.5 } @array) {
     print "Pass!"
}
```

It will even short-circuit for you, terminating as soon as it finds first false value, producing most speed-effective result.

Comment: cool! is List::Util something already installed in Perl? it seems that I need to install it myself, or not? i got this error trying to use all: "all" is not exported by the List::Util module

Comment: @user2157668 List::Util is a part of the core Perl distribution, but you may need to update it if you're on an older Perl. `all` wasn't [added](https://metacpan.org/changes/distribution/Scalar-List-Utils) until List::Util v1.33 (October 2013). Run `cpan List::Util` to update.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Is this the one to download? http://search.cpan.org/~pevans/Scalar-List-Utils-1.38/lib/List/Util.pm#SYNOPSIS

Comment: @user2157668 Easier to just use the `cpan` shell: `cpan List::Util` will install the latest version.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, *may*?? No stable version of Perl has yet included List::Util 1.33 or above. Only the unstable 5.19.5+ releases have. The latest stable release of Perl includes List::Util 1.27.

Comment: @user2157668, you can get this function from `List::MoreUtils` too.

Answer (score 2):

```
my @array = 10 .. 20;

# compare size of array with list size of grep
if (@array == grep { $_ > 0.5 } @array) {

  print "All are greater than 0.5\n";
}
```

Comment: @user2157668 some older versions of `List::Util` might not have `all` function

Comment: Stating the obvious but even without List::Util, wouldn't a `for` loop be better than `grep`? That way you could bail out once you found a value <= 0.5

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot IMO, this would make sense only for very large arrays.

Comment: Perhaps. The OP asked how to do this "efficiently" but I think they really meant "cleanly," in which case your solution is fine.

Comment: I actually have a few other tests on the values of each line and for now, checking if a line fits in the category of every entry larger than a value is easier to handle than checking if one is smaller. i guess i should change the title a little bit

Comment: @mpapec, in such case you can get it from `List::MoreUtils` too.